# Why the changes made in a page isn't taking any effect in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I created my project using `npx create-next-app new-app`. Then started it by `npm run dev`.

Then I deleted everything in the div and now my index.js looks like this:

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      Hi
    </div>
  )
}
```

But in the browser, it seems like the initial next.js page.

Why isn't the changes taking effect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1- Remove `.next` folder

2- run `npm run build`

3-now run `npm run dev` or `npm run start`

sometimes `Next js` has problems with its cached files

Comment: @Moen I did. But still the same.

Comment: @Moen I'm on a new pc. I installed vs-code and node.js. Is there something missing that I need to install?

Comment: nope , `node@lts` would be enough

Comment: Also, when I make any changes in the code, there's supposed to be a 'compiled server and client successfully' message. It isn't there when I make any changes.

Comment: I don't know , your problem is so generic

Comment: try re building your project with `npx create-next-app`

Comment: I haven't managed to get a solution yet. I tried reinstalling vscode and nodejs, but still the same result. How do I contact nextjs developer team? can you please tell me?

Comment: Yes you can contact them via their github

Comment: someone in GitHub pointed out the solution to the problem. I forgot to save the file. Before I was auto-saving the file so, I didn't need to save the file every time I made any changes. It works now.